# How do I launch Safari Web driver using Selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, safari, safaridriver

I have installed the latest available version of Safari driver i.e 2.48.
I am launching it using python script. The driver is launched but by default goes in private mode. And my application does not support private browsing. Is there any setting that needs to taken care of? Any suggestions would be great. This is the line which is launching:

```
driver = webdriver.Safari()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you install SafariDriver browser extension? https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/SafariDriver

Answer (score 0):

[Safari Driver](https://webkit.org/blog/6900/webdriver-support-in-safari-10/) is run in Private mode. You have no choice.

I've raised an issue to Apple in 2016, and they said the similar issue has already been raised and they are working on it. Here is the ticket [28137091](https://bugreport.apple.com/web/?problemID=28137091) that they referred to. I don't have an access so I have no idea about the current progress.

Answer (score 0):

Latest version have this issue i.e. it is always open in Private window

Use older versions of Safari and Selenium//SafariDriver, e.g. Safari 6-9 & Selenium 2.x, which don't have this restriction.

Answer (score 0):

Apple's safaridriver always uses ephemeral (i.e., "private") tabs for automation, with some minor relaxations between parent and child tabs to not break some cross-frame communication. You can read the rationale here: https://webkit.org/blog/6900/webdriver-support-in-safari-10/

The radar link upthread is for an unrelated issue, where local storage does not work in private browsing mode. That issue has been fixed for WebDriver and for normal Private Browsing in Safari 11. It would be helpful to know why your site does not work in private browsing, if it is not the aforementioned local storage issue.